# Why is the button click event not handled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I'm doing a simple NodeJS-MongoDB todo list application where the todo-items added can be updated. When the edit button is clicked, I'm changing the corresponding element to a form to update it. The edit button when pressed is successfully handled and is converted to a form, whereas when the update button is clicked it is not handled by the event listener and the default refresh action takes place. Why?

**Javascript Part:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.update').on('click', function(){
      var id =  $(this).parent().find('input:hidden');
      var item = $(this).parent().find('input:text');
      var priority =$(this).parent().find('select option:selected');
      var todo = {item: item.val(), priority: priority.val()}
      $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/todo/' + id.val(),
        data: todo,
        success: function(data){
          location.reload();
        }
      });
  });

$('.edit').on('click', function(){
    var id =  $(this).parent().find('input:hidden');
    var item = $(this).parent().find('b');
    $(this).parent().html(
        "<form>"+
        "<input type = 'text' name = 'item' value='" + item.text() + "' required />"+
        "<select name = 'priority' required>"+
        "<option value = 'high'> High </option>"+
        "<option value = 'medium'> Medium </option>"+
        "<option value = 'low'> Low </option>"+
        "</select>"+
        "<input type = 'hidden' value='" + id.val() + "'/>"+
        "<button class = 'update'> Update Item </button>"+
        "</form>");
  });
});
```

**HTML Part:**

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i < todos.length; i++){ %>
        <li>
        <input type = "hidden" value = <%= todos[i]._id %> /> 
        <b> <%= todos[i].item %> </b>
        <button class = "edit">  </button>
        </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page was dynamically creating elements with the class name dosomething you would bind the event to a parent which already exists, often "document"

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
 // what you want to happen when click
 // occurs on elements that match '.update'
});
```

Or you can use a parent DOM element, That always remain in your page load  Eg:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.update', function(){
 // do something here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve your problem

```
$(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
    //Rest of your code
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put `console.log();` to double check if it is going in. Button in a form's default action is going to form's action page which you don't have and you are not doing any POST, GET etc. with form, you are doing it with ajax. If you don't want to use form's functionality, you can just give `type=button` to button. If you are going to not use the form to post, get or anything in the future, removing the form tag is another option.

**EDIT**

After other answers, I noticed that the correct answer can be given by mixing my and their answers. So I decided to add this part too. You are giving onClick eventhandler before the DOM element was created. You must give event handler after creating the element. Your options here are:

- Adding the whole `.update` onClick inside `.edit` onClick's bottom.
- Giving onClick event handler to an object which was already created before any javascript action.

  ```
  $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
      //update's onClick actions here
  }
  ```

Comment: It isn't going inside the handler itself. I tried `console.log()` out. And if I add, `type=button`, it isn't going inside the handler as well as not refreshing.

Comment: You need to mix my answer with other ones to get correct result.

Comment: Because you are printing the button after giving it onclick handler.